# I'm trying to get data from the currentUser in my Parse Database, but I am getting an error after I updated to Xcode 6.3

Tags: swift, parse-platform, syntax-error, xcode6.3

I'm newer to Swift and I'm trying to get data from the currentUser in my Parse Database, but I am getting an error after I updated to Xcode 6.3. I have made a function called currentUserInfo and I am querying the data from my User class in the parse cloud. The error says: Cannot invoke 'findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list type '(([AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> Void'

```
  func currentUserInfo () {

    var query = PFUser.query()

    query!.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)

    query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock  {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            let user = PFUser.currentUser()

            var firstname = user["fbUsername"] as! String

            var email = user["email"] as! String

            var facebookId = user["fbId"] as! String


        }

    }
}
```

Also I was able to avoid this error by changing

```
      (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!)
```

to

```
(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?)
```

But when I did this it gave me errors on each of these lines:

```
           var firstname = user["fbUsername"] as! String

            var email = user["email"] as! String

            var facebookId = user["fbId"] as! String
```

Error: 'AnyObject?' is not convertible to 'String'

How can I get this up and running?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `[AnyObject]` to `Set<NSObject>`. I did this with `touch: Set<NSObject>` and it works for me.